# Styling links using CSS

Tags: php, css

I am trying to give style to my links and I am using this order:

```
a{}
a:visited{}
a:focus{}
a:hover{}
a:active{}
```

(I am not using a:link... I just use the id's to make the links work.)

The thing is that my "a" & "a:hover" are working but "a:visited" & "a:active" are not!!!
Is there a solution? I am only tying to give different color to "a:active":

```
a:active{
 font-family: gabriola, verdana; font-size: 26px; color: #e6e8fa; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle; border: none; outline: none;
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? See http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link for an example. Your code seems to be correct.

Comment: a:active is not... because my "links" look like this <a id=goto"> Then I am retrieving the id and sent the user where I need to. "a" and "a:hover" are working. "a:active" not... And I think @Kerrek is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>`active` doesn't make sense for non-link anchors</s> (not sure about this actually, `:active` might be triggered on *any* visible element). Use this:

```
a:link, a:visited               // normal links
a:link:hover, a:visited:hover   // link with mouse-over
a:link:active, a:visited:active // link being clicked (mouse-down, etc.)
```

Also available, but less specific:

```
a        // any anchor
a:hover  // any anchor with mouse-over
```

The latter two will have their properties overridden by the more specific ones above if the anchor actually has the `href` attribute set.

Comment: But using **"a:link"** I will have to **add href=""** to my anchors to work right?

Comment: Well, what do you want to style? `a:link` styles anchors with `href`, while `a` styles _all_ anchors.

Comment: Oh, perhaps you can actually apply `:active` to *all* elements. I'm not sure if that's standardized behaviour, the spec only says "while an element is being activated by the user".

Comment: I want to style my anchor that works as a link, without including href... And as you 're saying I cannot do that for active links...?

Comment: @Pavlos1316 — in order to work as a link, you need an `href` attribute. That is how you create links.

Comment: You can definitely style `:hover` for all elements, and perhaps even `:active`. If you don't have `href`, just style `a` and `a:hover`.

Comment: To clarify: `active` refers to any element that is currently undergoing some user action -- essentially that means any element that is currently being mouse-downed on.

Comment: Ok... I got that... Last question (I don't know if is stupid to make it like this, but... Can I insert **href="" in my anchor** and at the same time use my **anchor id** to sent the user where I want?

Comment: You mean use an anchor both as a link and as a link target for a fragment identifier like `#this`? Sure: `<a href="..." name="this">Text</a>`. If you're modern, say `id` rather than `name`.

Comment: something like **<a href="" id="goto">** I am using the id to open "link pages". I just need the href to be able to style my links. Can I leave it empty?

Comment: Don't put a `href` in if you don't want to make a link! Just style `a {...}` directly, or even `a#goto` if it's just this element. Or add a class, `<a class="myanchor" id="goto">...`, and style `a.myanchor`.

Comment: lol I think I confused you... let me try to explain it again... I want to use a:active... Which as you said is working only for links (href)... But for my "links" I am just using the anchor's id to open new pages. I don't use href... So can I add href in order to use a:link:active but without a value in it? so I still use my anchor's id to open new pages???

Comment: Can you just post that somewhere and I'll style it for you? Also, how do you open new pages without a link??

Comment: @Kerrek I just needed to use a:active... Rest of styling I did it... And as you are saying I cannot do it if I don't use href...

Answer (score 2):

I read somewhere (a quick Google suggests it could have been *anywhere*) that it's easy to remember the order for anchor styling declarations using the mnemonic **L** o **V** e / **H A** t e:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```